# Пытаюсь добавить в список объекты класса, но выдает ошибку "выход за границы указанного диапазона"

Tags: c#, ооп

Код выглядит как-то так: (отрывок именно с данной проблемой):

```
        Console.Write("\nДля задания класса Series (набор), вводите количество вносимых в него объектов классов Integer/Double: ");
        int count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        var series = new List<Number>(count);
```

//Number - основной. класс, имеющий два дочерних: Integer и Real

```
        Console.WriteLine("Вводите значения объектов через Enter, потом введите stop: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            string get_input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (get_input == "stop")
            {
                break;
            }
            if (int.TryParse(get_input, out int_value))
            {
                Integer new_integer = new Integer();
                new_integer.value = int_value;
                series[i] = new_integer;
```

//Series - массив, куда будут закидываться объекты классов Integer и Real

```
            }
            else if (double.TryParse(get_input, out double_value))
            {
                Real new_real = new Real();
                new_real.value = double_value;
                series[i] = new_real;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ведено неверное значение.");
            }
```

Я новичок в С#, ничего не понимаю, заранее извиняюсь за глупые ошибки

Comment: в вопрос нужно вставлять текст ошибок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использованный конструктор создаёт список, задавая его **вместимость**:

```
var series = new List<Number>(count);
```

Указывая вместимость, вы задаёте начальный размер массива, в котором список "под капотом" хранит элементы. Настоящее количество элементов `Count` в списке **НЕ** одно и тоже, что его вместимость `Capacity`.

Когда вы создали список через этот конструктор, `Count` равняется 0. По-этому при обращении `series[i]` вы получаете `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

В вашем случае, достаточно заменить

```
series[i] = ...;
```

на

```
series.Add(...);
```

Comment: Благодарю! Все теперь работает. Доброго дня :)

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае `List<Number>` это `generic`, т.е. **класс** со своими методами, без инициализации он имеет нулевую длину. Напомню что `[0]` - это обращение к первому элементу, т.е. длина массива должна быть `1`
Для того чтобы использовать `[]` нужно чтобы там уже были элементы:

```
var series = List<Number>{0, 1, 3.14}
```

Если бы объявление было таким то ошибки не было, элементы присутствуют.
Но так как объявление без начальной инициализации то для добавления элемента следует писать так:

```
series.Add(new_integer);
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Все теперь работает)